# How Dual table support date format?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Dual table type format is `varchar2(1)`, Then how is it possible to support date function.

EX:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What do u mean by Dual Table type ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Comment: Dual is just a dummy table.

Answer (score 1):

`DUAL` table has only one column - `dummy varchar2(1)`  and one row and has value `'X'`.

so, if you query

`select dummy from dual` gives you

```
| DUMMY |
|-------|
|     X |
```

In the query  `SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;`, dual table just acts as an anchor table on which you can run a query to get a single row, since Oracle is yet to provide a plain select clause (  `select 'yourname' as name;` ) available in SQL Server and many other databases.

You should be knowing that whatever may be the number and type of column in the table, you can always run a query selecting a function / a string / a number etc from it including or excluding those columns.

For eg: If you have an `EMPLOYEE` table in your schema, you are aware that this query is perfectly valid although no other columns are in the `select` list.

The only difference in running this query on `dual` is, instead of 1 row, this will return the value returned from the function( `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)`), displaying as many rows as contained in the `EMPLOYEES` table. You see that this isn't useful to you unless you are actually querying employees table.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) as mon FROM EMPLOYEES;

MON
--
4
4
4
4
4
4
..
..
```

So, you would want a **standard table** which always returns one row and one or multiple columns, which rests the case for `DUAL` in Oracle for now.